# DBNull warnings when performing stored procedure

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

One column in my database (of type double) has some null values.
I am executing a sored procedure to get the data in my app

```
 wipDBTableAdapters.XLSFacturiTableAdapter TAFacturi = new wipDBTableAdapters.XLSFacturiTableAdapter();
               var dtfacturi = TAFacturi.GetData(CodProiect);
```

Then i try to do something like this:

```
if (dtfacturi[i].CANTITATE == null)
   {
    //do something
   }
```

this is giving a warning :

```
The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'double' is never equal to 'null' of type 'double?
```

However when i run my code i get the following exception:

```
StrongTypingException
The value for column 'CANTITATE' in table 'XLSFacturi' is DBNull.
```

How am I supposed to resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While working with data in DB and need to check NULL values use [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) class instead of .NET null.

Comment: unfortunately i get the same result with DBNull, i think i will add a stored procedure that  will replace null with 0 in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Database NULLs are different from `null`, you should use `IsDBNull` to check for database NULLs.

Edit: Mixed up VB.Net with C#

Compare with `DBNull.Value` rather than the VB specific `IsDBNull`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (dtfacturi[i].CANTITATE == DBNull.Value)
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A value of type 'double' is indeed never null; if you want to export into an array of doubles, you need to have two columns in the database, one containing the data and one containing a flag as to whether the data is valid or not.

This is really a bug in your database-to-array adapter code; I can't find any google hits for XLSFacturiTableAdapter so I'm not sure who to shout at.

Answer (score 0):

`DBNull` is not `null`

Check [DBNull documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx)

Try this test :

```
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dtfacturi[i].CANTITATE))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using TypedDataSets, check if coloumn is null this way..

```
   if (dtfacturi[i].IsCANTITATENull()) 
   { 
       //do something 
   }
```

Also note that, C# null is different than Database null. Type of your coloumn is double which is a value type that can never be null. In order to check if your coloumn value is null you need to compare it with DBNull.Value.